# Not able to drop a table in db2 luw 9.7

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have created a table with the name `"SCHEMA"."CARD_key_1"`.

```
CREATE TABLE "SCHEMA"."CARD_key_1"  (

              "CARD_SKEY" BIGINT NOT NULL ,

              "CARD_ENCRYPT" VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL )

             COMPRESS YES

             DISTRIBUTE BY HASH("CARD_ENCRYPT");

               IN "TS_05" INDEX IN "TS_IDX_05" ;
```

Now when I am trying to drop this table, its not allowing me to drop.

`db2 drop table schema.card_key_1`

kindly guide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you created your table you enclosed the table name in double quotes, which effectively made the name case-sensitive. Now you have to quote the table name each time you refer to it. If the table name (or other identifier) is not quoted, it will be converted to the upper case by default. In addition to that you need to ensure that the shell where you run the `drop` statement does not interpret the quotation marks:

```
db2 'drop table schema."CARD_key_1"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try db2 "drop table .".
Also, try to see the table by using: 
db2 describe table .. If table has double quotes then use the same. Please let us know the results. Thank you.